# Is it possible to write dynamic queries for views?

Tags: mysql, dynamic, view

Is it allowed to write queries with dynamic source table? the system that I am developing creates a backup of the current database per week. so the most active database would be ***mainDB***, the previous week backup would be named as ***mainDb20170327***, and the week before that would be ***mainDb20170320***

I need to create a dynamic view that is hosted in each of these database instances. so ***mainDb*** has a view named ***view_mainDb***, and ***mainDb20170320*** has a view named ***view_mainDb20170320***.

In the sql query of the view, how can I make the source db instance dynamic?

I tried to user adding the text and concatenating but it doesn't seem to be possible. Or I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of a view must be fixed. You can't make any part of it dynamic.

You'll have to write a stored procedure to do what you want to do, or else do it in application code.